# $x\mapsto x^k$ is an automorphism on $C_n$ iff $\gcd(n,k)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G = \langle g\rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $n$ (with multiplication as its operation). Prove that $f(x) = x^k$ is an automorphism on $G$ if and only if $\gcd(n, k) = 1$.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I really just don't know how to start it

Comment: I would start by trying some specific examples to get your head around the problem. Take a cyclic group $G$ of order $6$ generated by a generator $g$: $G = \{e, g, g^2, g^3, g^4, g^5\}$, and consider, for example, $f(x) = x^2$. So, for example, $f(g^4) = g^8 = g^6g^2 = g^2$. Note that $\operatorname{gcd}(6, 2) > 1$, so it shouldn't be an automorphism. Try investigating why: is it a homomorphism? Is it a bijection? Does it have a non-trivial kernel (and if so, what is it)? If it's not surjective, then what is its range? Do a little exploration, and perhaps the path forward will be clearer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Your question is stated as an isolated problem without any context or effort of your own. It is likely to attract down votes and get closed. Please improve your question. Reading [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) might be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to use additive notation for the cyclic group here. Let $C_n : = \{1,2,3,\dots,n-1\}$ be the cyclic group of order $n$

Forward case: assume $f : C_n \to C_n$ where $f(x) = kx$ is an automorphism. Then, it must be the case that
$$f(\langle x \rangle) = \langle kx \rangle = \langle x \rangle$$
This is only true if $\gcd(n,k)=1$, hence the desired reult.

Backwards case: assume $\gcd(k,n)=1$ and $f : C_n \to C_n$ where $f(x)=kx$. We need to show that $f$ is an isomorphism (and hence an automorphism). First, let us show it is a homomorphism. Pick any $x,y \in C_n$. Then:
$$f(x+y) = k(x+y) = kx+ky = f(x)+f(y)$$
hence $f$ is a homomorphism. Next, to show it is an isomorphism, we need to show it is bijective. Since obviously $|C_n|=|C_n|$, we just need to show $f$ is injective to show it is bijective. Choose any $x,y \in C_n$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Then,
$$f(x)=f(y) \implies kx=ky$$
Since $gcd(k,n)=1$, it must be the case that $x=y$, so $f$ is an injection, and hence bijective, so $f$ is an automorphism.

Comment: Your cyclic group of order $n$ has only $n-1$ elements and no identity element!

Answer (score 0):

Since $G$ is cyclic, let $g$ be a generator.  That is, suppose $G=\langle g\rangle$.  Then since the order of $g^k$ is $n/\rm{gcd}(n,k)$, we have that under the mapping $x\stackrel{f}\mapsto x^k$, $g$ goes to another generator if and only if $\rm{gcd}(n,k)=1$.  In these cases, and only these cases, $f$ is an automorphism.